# Saving API text to textfile PYTHON

Tags: python, request

I have an api that allows you to download proxies. Every time I try to save this to a note file on python, it saves it with spaces. If I print it however, there are no spaces to be found. Why is this happening and how can I remove the spaces?

```
import requests
proxyrequest = requests.get("https://api.proxyscrape.com?request=getproxies&proxytype=http")
with open("proxies.txt", "w") as proxywrite:
    proxywrite.write(proxyrequest.text)
```

What I get:

```
1.10.189.84:44452

1.0.160.41:4145

1.0.150.125:4145

1.10.188.93:37389

1.0.142.155:4145

1.0.155.32:4145

1.0.220.235:4145

1.0.161.67:4145

114.104.137.34:1080
```

What I need:

```
1.10.189.84:44452
1.0.160.41:4145
1.0.150.125:4145
1.10.188.93:37389
1.0.142.155:4145
1.0.155.32:4145
1.0.220.235:4145
1.0.161.67:4145
114.104.137.34:1080
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works fine :)

```
import requests
proxyrequest = requests.get("https://api.proxyscrape.com?request=getproxies&proxytype=http")
proxyrequest_format = proxyrequest.text.strip()
proxyrequest_format = proxyrequest_format.replace("\r","")
list_proxies = list(proxyrequest_format.split("\n"))
with open("proxies.txt", "w") as proxywrite:
    for proxy in list_proxies:
        proxywrite.write("%s\n" % proxy)
```

Output:

```
1.10.188.202:8080
1.0.210.16:8080
1.119.166.180:8080
1.10.188.85:8080
1.197.204.40:9999
01.10.188.202:8080
1.0.190.69:8080
1.2.254.185:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the '\n' in the text. You can fix it by removing '\n' from the text. Use the following code instead:

```
proxywrite.write(proxyrequest.text.replace('\n',''))
```